# StartWith() after Switch() except on initial subscription

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an `IObservable<string>` that is `Switch()`ed out every time a different `IObservable` emits a value, like so:

```
IObservable<string> Invalidated => stateChanged
    .Select(state => state.CanExecuteChanged.Select(x => _myString))
    .Switch()
    .StartWith(_myString);
```

Here, `stateChanged` is an `IObservable<State>` and `CanExecuteChanged` is an `IObservable<bool>`. In other words, every time the state changes, I unsubscribe from that `state`'s `CanExecuteChanged` observable and subscribe to the observable provided by the new state.

The issue is with `StartWith`. The first time I subscribe *I don't want a value to be emitted*. However, every time `Switch` runs as a consequence of state change *I do want a value to be emitted*. Stated otherwise, no value should be emitted on the initial subscription to `Invalidated`, but on every `Switch` hence, I do want a value to be emitted. Can I acheive this, and, if so, how?

Comment: Why not move the `StartWith` into the projection? `stateChanged.Select(state => state.CanExecuteChanged.Select(x => _myString).StartWith(_myString))`. That way a value is guaranteed to be emitted every time the switch happens.

Comment: @Asti Unfortunately that doesn't work. `Invalidate`does now not emit values when `CanExecuteChanged` does.

Comment: @Asti - it does indeed emit a value when the switch happens, but unfortunately the CanExecuteChanged observable is not subscribed to on `Subscribe()`.

Comment: Could you post a minimal reproducible example? I'm interested in figuring this out.

Comment: @Asti - I can, but you'll have to give me 30 minutes. In the meantime, if you make `stateChanged`a `Subject<State>` where `State` has an `IObservable` `CanExecuteChanged` that emits `bool`s, it's pretty straightforward to reproduce.

Comment: @AlexanderHøst - Would a simple solution like `.Skip(1)` work?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that @Asti was right here. Here are some test showing that, by moving the StartWith inside the projection:

1. No value is emitted on initial subscription
2. An "initial" value is emitted when the State observable emits a new value
3. A "changed"value is emitted when the CanExecuteChanged observable changes

```cs
public class State
{
    public State(IObservable<bool> canExecuteChanged)
    {
        CanExecuteChanged = canExecuteChanged;
    }

    public IObservable<bool> CanExecuteChanged { get; }
}

public class StartWithAfterSwitch
{
    private IObservable<string> CreateObservable(IObservable<State> state)
    {
        return state
            .Select(s => s.CanExecuteChanged.Select(_ => "changed").StartWith("initial"))
            .Switch();
    }

    [Test]
    public void ShouldNotEmmitOnInitialSubscription()
    {
        var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

        var states = scheduler.CreateColdObservable<State>();

        var observed = scheduler.Start(() => CreateObservable(states), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks);

        Assert.That(observed.Messages, Is.Empty);
    }

    [Test]
    public void ShouldEmitWhenStateChanges()
    {
        var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

        State stateA = new State(Observable.Never<bool>());

        var states = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
            new Recorded<Notification<State>>(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500).Ticks, Notification.CreateOnNext(stateA)) 
        );

        var observed = scheduler.Start(() => CreateObservable(states), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks);

        Assert.That(observed.Messages.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
        Assert.That(observed.Messages[0].Time, Is.EqualTo(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500).Ticks).Within(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1).Ticks));
        Assert.That(observed.Messages[0].Value.Value, Is.EqualTo("initial"));
    }

    [Test]
    public void ShouldEmitWhenCanExecuteChanges()
    {
        var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

        State stateA = new State(scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
            new Recorded<Notification<bool>>(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100).Ticks, Notification.CreateOnNext(true))
        ));

        var states = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
            new Recorded<Notification<State>>(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500).Ticks, Notification.CreateOnNext(stateA))
        );

        var observed = scheduler.Start(() => CreateObservable(states), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks);

        Assert.That(observed.Messages.Count, Is.EqualTo(2));
        Assert.That(observed.Messages[0].Time, Is.EqualTo(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500).Ticks).Within(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1).Ticks));
        Assert.That(observed.Messages[0].Value.Value, Is.EqualTo("initial"));

        Assert.That(observed.Messages[1].Time, Is.EqualTo(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600).Ticks).Within(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1).Ticks));
        Assert.That(observed.Messages[1].Value.Value, Is.EqualTo("changed"));
    }
}
```